# AngularJS: How to show single quote in expression

Tags: angularjs

i am beginner in angular js. so i tried this code but output does not look good

```
<div ng-app>

    Write some text in textbox:
    <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

    <h1>Hello 
    <p ng-show="sometext">'</p>{{ sometext }}<p ng-show="sometext">'</p>
    </h1>

</div>
```

i want to show single quote around **sometext expresion** but if some test is null or empty then quote should not be shown. tell me how to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>

    Write some text in textbox:
    <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

    <h1>Hello 
    <p ng-show="sometext">{{'\''+sometext +'\''}}</p>
    </h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason why they're in two separate paragraph elements? Something like this should work:

```
<p ng-show="sometext">'{{ sometext }}'</p>
```

if you want the name to appear on the same line as "Hello", you'll have to change it to a `span`.

```
<span ng-show="sometext">'{{ sometext }}'</span>
```